# how to sum total and use it in each row in mysql

Tags: mysql

hi I'm trying since yesterday to get the sum of each previous row and use it in the next row but I got the wrong results, my SQL statement is:

```
SELECT `RegDate`,`RegdM2`,`RegdD2`,
(@s := @s + `RegdM2`-`RegdD2`) as xresult
from tblregs2 b
cross join (select @s := 0) c
INNER JOIN tblregs1 a ON b.RegRef = a.RegRef
WHERE `RegdAccID`=32
ORDER BY RegDate
```

tblregs1 definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblregs1` (
`RegID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`RegRef` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`RegCode` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`RegDate` date NOT NULL,
`RegCurr` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `tblregs1` (`RegID`, `RegRef`, `RegCode`, `RegDate`, `RegCurr`,         
`RegDetails`, `RegType`, `RegStatus`) VALUES
(1, 202010011140192, '', '2020-10-01', 1),
(2, 202010011141252, '', '2020-10-01', 1),
(3, 202010011141562, '', '2020-10-01', 1),
(4, 202010011143242, '', '2020-10-02', 0),
(5, 202010010103422, '', '2020-10-01', 1),
(6, 202010020836472, '', '2020-10-01', 0),
(7, 202010030101142, '', '2020-10-02', 0),
(8, 202010030101272, '', '2020-10-02', 0),
(9, 202010030101392, '', '2020-10-02', 0),
(10, 202010030101522, '', '2020-10-02', 0),
(11, 202010030102112, '', '2020-10-02', 0),
(12, 202010030153562, '', '2020-10-03', 1),
(14, 202010030158322, '', '2020-10-03', 1),
(15, 202010030431432, '', '2020-10-02', 0),
(16, 202010030439122, '', '2020-10-01', 1),
(17, 202010030512263, '', '2020-10-01', 1),
(18, 202010030515133, '', '2020-10-03', 2),
(19, 202010041255541, '', '2020-10-02', 1);
```

tblregs2 definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblregs2` (
`RegdID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`RegRef` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`RegdM1` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RegdD1` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RegdAccID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`RegdDetails` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`RegdCurrPrice` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RegdM2` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RegdD2` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RecStatus` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Normal',
`RegdNo` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`RegdMtbkRaseed` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RegdMtbkFark` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RegdMtbkStatus` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`RegdMtbkNotes` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `tblregs2` (`RegdID`, `RegRef`, `RegdM1`, `RegdD1`,      
`RegdAccID`, `RegdDetails`, `RegdCurrPrice`, `RegdM2`, `RegdD2`,     
`RecStatus`, `RegdNo`, `RegdMtbkRaseed`, `RegdMtbkFark`, `RegdMtbkStatus`, 
`RegdMtbkNotes`) VALUES
(1, 202010011140192, 1000, 0, 916, 'Des1', 1, 1000, 0, 'Normal', 0, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(4, 202010011141252, 0, 10000, 32, 'Des1', 1, 0, 10000, 'Normal', 2, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(13, 202010011143242, 1680, 0, 32, 'Des1', 1, 1680, 0, 'Normal', 3, -8320, 
0, 'no', 'no'),
(14, 202010011143242, 0, 1680, 15, 'Des1', 1, 0, 1680, 'Normal', 4, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(16, 202010011143242, 0, 10, 32, 'Des1', 1, 0, 10, 'Normal', 6, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(17, 202010011143242, 15, 0, 32, 'Des1', 1, 15, 0, 'Normal', 7, -8315, 0, 
'', '-8315'),
(19, 202010011143242, 450000, 0, 32, 'Des1', 1235, 364.37, 0, 'Normal', 9, 
0, 0, '', ''),
(20, 202010011143242, 0, 450000, 306, 'Des1', 1, 0, 450000, 'Normal', 10, 
0, 0, NULL, NULL),
(33, 202010020836472, 0, 0, 916, '', 0, 0, 0, 'Normal', 9, 0, 0, NULL, 
NULL),
(34, 202010020836472, 0, 0, 86, '', 0, 0, 0, 'Normal', 10, 0, 0, NULL, 
NULL),
(35, 202010030153562, 1400, 0, 32, 'Des1', 32, 1400, 0, 'Normal', 0, 
-6550.63, 0, '', '12'),
(36, 202010030153562, 0, 1400, 55, 'Des1', 55, 0, 1400, 'Normal', 0, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(38, 202010030158322, 0, 7000, 32, 'Des1', 1, 0, 7000, 'Normal', 2, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(64, 202010041255541, 0, 4500, 32, 'Des1', 1, 0, 4500, 'Normal', 2, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(65, 202010041255541, 10, 0, 33, 'Des1', 1, 10, 0, 'Normal', 3, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(66, 202010041255541, 0, 10, 45, 'Des1', 1, 0, 10, 'Normal', 4, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL);
```

example of my data for the specified user is:

```
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
| RegID |  RegDate  | RegdID | RegdAccID | RegdM2 | RegdD2 |
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|   2   | 10/1/2020 |    4   |     32    |    0   |  10000 |
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|   4   | 10/2/2020 |   13   |     32    |  1680  |    0   |
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|   4   | 10/2/2020 |   16   |     32    |    0   |   10   |
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|   4   | 10/2/2020 |   17   |     32    |   15   |    0   |
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|   4   | 10/2/2020 |   19   |     32    | 364.37 |    0   |
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|   12  | 10/3/2020 |   35   |     32    |  1400  |    0   |
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|   14  | 10/3/2020 |   38   |     32    |    0   |  7000  |
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|   19  | 10/2/2020 |   64   |     32    |    0   |  4500  |
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

this is the result that gives me:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
|  RegDate  | RegdID | RegdM2 | RegdD2 |   Result  |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 10/1/2020 |    4   |    0   |  10000 |   -10000  |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 10/2/2020 |   13   |  1680  |    0   |   -8320   |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 10/2/2020 |   16   |    0   |   10   |   -8330   |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 10/2/2020 |   17   |   15   |    0   |   -8315   |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 10/2/2020 |   19   | 364.37 |    0   |  -7950.63 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 10/2/2020 |   64   |    0   |  4500  | -18050.63 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 10/3/2020 |   35   |  1400  |    0   |  -6550.63 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 10/3/2020 |   38   |    0   |  7000  | -13550.63 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
```

now I added all the requested data, hope that will help
thanks, advanced

Comment: Your ordering expression does not provide definite rows ordering (each row must be unique using this expression). So expand sorting expression until each row is unique by this expression.

Comment: But the best way is to upgrade the server to 8+ and use window function for retrieving the cumulative sum. PS. Do not use FLOAT/DOUBLE for an attribute which needs in strict value - use DECIMAL.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: dear @Strawberry the link that you provide didn't solve my problem, please aware that I'm a beginner so please just give me more explanation if you can, please don't just give me a link

Comment: I'm satisfied that the link is self explanatory.

Comment: *the link that you provide didn't solve my problem* You have to solve your problem, that is, work to solve it, you don't have to sit in front of the screen and wait for someone to solve your problem. Minimal Reproducible Example creation is a kind of such work.

Comment: @Akina I told in my main post that I tried many solutions and I'm still working on it, I'm not sitting in front of the screen, anyway, thank you

Comment: @Akina when I changed the order reference to "RegdID" I got the correct result, but the problem is I want to keep the date field for ordering, I tried and tried but really I don't know what the problem

Comment: Please add your table definition, sample data and expected result as text to the question.  It's difficult to guess what you are doing from non working code and an unlabeled image dump.

Comment: *I told in my main post that I tried many solutions and I'm still working on it, I'm not sitting in front of the screen, anyway, thank you* And you can't spare two minutes to write and add to the text of the question CREATE TABLE for tables, INSERT INTO with some sample rows for which you need to calculate something, and show the desired output for this data?

Comment: *when I changed the order reference to "RegdID" I got the correct result, but the problem is I want to keep the date field for ordering* Why not `ORDER BY RegDate, RegdID`, for example?

Comment: @Akina I tried  "ORDER BY RegDate, RegdID" but it gives me the same results it calculates the amount by order by regdid, sorry and I added more info for the main post

Comment: @P.Salmon done, I added more information

Comment: *`CREATE TABLE` for tables, `INSERT INTO` with some sample rows*. Not pictures.

Comment: I see another output: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=efe43ac4ff2dc2e110509fbb188699d3). Edit fiddle, insert YOUR structures and data, provide a link to new fiddle with the output which is incorrect.

Comment: @Akina I added all information

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222526/discussion-between-hamada-and-akina).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 5.x version:

```sql
SELECT d.RegDate, 
       d.RegdID,
       d.RegdM2, 
       d.RegdD2, 
       CAST(@s := @s + d.RegdM2-d.RegdD2 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS xresult
FROM (SELECT a.RegDate,
             b.RegdM2, 
             b.RegdD2, 
             b.RegdID
       FROM tblregs2 b
       INNER JOIN tblregs1 a ON b.RegRef = a.RegRef
       WHERE b.RegdAccID=32 ) d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s := 0) c
ORDER BY d.RegDate, 
         d.RegdID;
```

For 8+ version and one account:

```sql
SELECT a.RegDate,
       b.RegdID,
       b.RegdM2, 
       b.RegdD2, 
       CAST(SUM(b.RegdM2-b.RegdD2) OVER (PARTITION BY RegdAccID 
                                         ORDER BY a.RegDate, b.RegdID) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) xresult
FROM tblregs2 b
INNER JOIN tblregs1 a ON b.RegRef = a.RegRef
WHERE b.RegdAccID=32
ORDER BY a.RegDate,
         b.RegdID;
```

For 8+ version and all accounts:

```sql
SELECT b.RegdAccID,
       a.RegDate,
       b.RegdID,
       b.RegdM2, 
       b.RegdD2, 
       CAST(SUM(b.RegdM2-b.RegdD2) OVER (PARTITION BY RegdAccID 
                                         ORDER BY a.RegDate, b.RegdID) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) xresult
FROM tblregs2 b
INNER JOIN tblregs1 a ON b.RegRef = a.RegRef
ORDER BY b.RegdAccID,
         a.RegDate,
         b.RegdID;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=53fe905b718bdb6bdded61f0e77901a1)

Comment: thank you for the SQL statement, I faced a problem when I tried to fill Datatable
`MySqlException: Parameter '@s' must be defined.`

Comment: This is not MySQL problem but your framework issue.

Comment: yes I know but how I can solve it please, I'm using .net Framework 4.7